# how to backup an HP procurve 4000M switch configuration

Tags: networking

How can I backup the configuration setting on a HP Procurve 4000M Switch so in the event of a failure, I can replace the switch and load the configuration?

Comment: Replace the switch with what? The HP ProCurve 4000 has been end-of-life for years.

Comment: The one I have in service has been in use for 10 years and I have another just like it brand new in the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install TFTP on a server/PC that the switch can reach, and use the `put` command inside the switch CLI to upload the configuration file to the TFTP server.

See page A-8 and A-9 [here](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/59676967.pdf)